# Relational model employee department and type of employee

Tags: relational-database

I have to do a Relations model of the employees with the 1.N department and then I have to have three types of employees, coordinator, treasurer or nothing. But the guy who coordinates the department is a 1.1, and the department treasurer has to be 1.N. the Relations model employee would look like this? id Employee, id Department, type, id Department Coordinator, id Department Treasurer[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6Tjv.png)

Comment: Hi. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. Use edit functions to inline, not link, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained. And never give a diagram without a legend/key.

Comment: Please give a reference/explanation re the method you are suppposed to follow & how you are supposed diagram including how you are supposed to record cardinalities & subtypes--*there are many methods*. What are the parts you are sure about, and what are you unsure about & why you are unsure & why you did them the way you did? Please read & act on hits googling 'stackexchange homework'.